# WSO2 rabbitMQ - channels created and not closed - memory leak problem

Tags: memory-leaks, rabbitmq, wso2, out-of-memory, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB with RabbitMQ, I have one proxy service and one sequence.

The proxy service works as consumer for RabbitMQ queue (via rabbitmq transport), consumed messages are send to HTTP endpoint.

The sequence works as producer to add actions in queue, calling an endpoint.

I also have an API that, for each call, inserts in the queue. Everything works correctly, but every time that we call the API, in the rabbit queue many channels are created without closing them, causing the "memory leak" problem on the Rabbit server machine.

We tried to create "direct" and "fanout" exchange, but did not resolve the memory leak problem.

Below the **sequence code**:

```
<sequence name="add-insertqueue-tostore" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="gov:endpoints/rabbit/insert-toqueue.xml"/>
    </call>
    <log level="full">
        <property name="Sequence" value="AddToQueue"/>
        <property name="step" value="Message inserted"/>
    </log>
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="false"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="false"/>
</sequence>
```

below the **endpoint code**

```
<endpoint name="insert-toqueue" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address uri="rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.server.host.name=rabbit.server&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=username&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=password&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=queue&amp;rabbitmq.server.virtual.host=/virtual-host&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange"/>
</endpoint>
```

below the **consumer code**

```
<proxy name="rabbit-consumer" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable" transports="rabbitmq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAPAction" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="WSAction" scope="transport"/>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="POST"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.name)" name="name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.surname)" name="surname" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <call-template target="my-template">
                <with-param name="name" value="{get-property('name')}" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
                <with-param name="surname" value="{get-property('surname')}" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            </call-template>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.type">fanout</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">exchange</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to reboot?

Normally it works.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

When configure RabbitMQ sender maybe u can try "cached" one.

```
<transportSender name="rabbitmq" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender">
   <parameter name="CachedRabbitMQConnectionFactory" locked="false">
     <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name" locked="false">localhost</parameter>
     <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port" locked="false">5672</parameter>
     <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name" locked="false">user</parameter>
     <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password" locked="false">abc123</parameter>
   </parameter>
</transportSender>
```

Doc link : https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport

Comment: Hi Hasitha, we tried your solution but always new channels are created after each call :-(